# Exporting a feature to a specific directory using drush

Tags: 7, drush, features

I am creating a new feature using drush. I looked up the component I want to create the feature with. When I run the command `drush fe my_feature views_view:my_cool_view`, drush wants to put it in `sites/all/modules`. How do I tell drush to export my feature to `sites/all/modules/custom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `drush fe my_feature views_view:my_cool_view --destination=sites/all/modules/custom`

https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/features/features-export/
http://dirtystylus.com/2016/02/18/setting-a-destination-directory-for-drush-features-export/

Bonus: To change the name of the feature, and other info, edit the `name=` section of: `sites/all/modules/custom/my_feature/my_feature.info`